# kvm memory changes via virsh not propagating to vm

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, rhel6

Hi I just started using kvm on rhel6 and after creating a vm I tried to increase the memory but the changes I amde in the xml file do not propogate to vm, even after bouncing vm and restarting libvert?

```
[root@kvm01 qemu]# virsh dominfo dev-kvm01
Id: 2
Name: dev-kvm01
UUID: 9b2bf581-2807-3116-b176-60e9c0559943
OS Type: hvm
State: running
CPU(s): 2
CPU time: 1975.3s
Max memory: 7864320 kB
Used memory: 7864320 kB
Persistent: yes
Autostart: disable
Security model: selinux
Security DOI: 0
Security label: system_u:system_r:svirt_t:s0:c47,c760 (enforcing)
[iknowmed@dev-kvm01 ~]$ free
           total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:     3632284    3614508      17776          0       3980    3491676
-/+ buffers/cache:   118852    3513432
Swap:    5668856          0    5668856
```

Comment: can you post the kvm cmd line? `ps -ef|grep qemu`

Answer (score 3):

I believe that in your guest you might have a x86 (32 bit) kernel without PAE (Physical Address Extension) support. Those kernels are only able to support less than 4 GB of memory.

The easy solution is to switch to PAE enabled kernel (hopefully) provided by your Linux distribution.

The more difficult solution is to switch to x86_64/amd64 (64 bit) architecture but then you need to re-install the guest.

**Edited to add:**

Alternatively you might not have PAE enabled in your libvirt configuration.

If you do `virsh edit dev-kvm01` you should see a *features* section such as follows:

```
<features>
    <pae/>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
</features>
```

If the `<pae/>` entry is not there, put it there and restart the guest.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following steps to increase memory size of your KVM virtual machine.

1. First shutdown vm
   `virsh shutdown dev-kvm01`
2. After completion, verify memory settings in vm xml file and then run
   `virsh undefine dev-kvm01`
   `virsh define dev-kvm01`
3. Now start vm
   `virsh start dev-kvm01`
4. Verify memory changes in the vm, I recommend not to use linux `free` program to check memory usage rather you can install a nice tool `htop`

`yum install htop # For Red Hat/ CentOS / Fedora`
`apt-get install htop # For Debian / Ubuntu / Linux Mint`

5. Run `htop`

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: 5. Run only a single command
   htop

Comment: 2. Easier this way: `virsh edit dev-kvm01`

Comment: The kernel ships with rhel6 already support PAE (more than 4 gb RAM) on 32bit architecture.